# Proving that countable intersection of G-$ \delta $ set is a G- $ \delta $ set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I am trying to prove that countable intersection of G-$ \delta $ set is a G- $ \delta $ set . 
I am trying to use countable union of F- $ \sigma $ is again a F-$ \sigma $ and that complement of G- $ \delta $ is F- $ \sigma $ and vice versa.  but I don't know how to deal with S \ $ 
\bigcap $ $ \bigcap $ G- $ \delta $ which I must prove F- $ \sigma $.
Can someone please help.

Comment: The proof for this doesn't seem to need to go through an $F$-$\sigma$ set. It is simply the case that $\cap_{m=1}^\infty \cap_{n=1}^\infty=\cap_I$ where $I=\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ and $I$ is countable.

Comment: $ S \smallsetminus \bigcap _ i \bigcap _ j G _ { i , j } = \bigcup _ i ( S \smallsetminus \bigcap _ j G _ { i , j } ) = \bigcup _ i \bigcup _ j ( S \smallsetminus G _ { i , j } ) $, which is a countable union of $ \mathrm F _ \sigma $ sets.

Comment: @TobyBartels  thank you very much.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, and you were shown a proof of the theorem for Fσs and asked to prove the theorem for Gδs, then it may be that you were expected to write an *analogous* proof for the analogous theorem, rather than to *use* the given theorem in your proof of the new theorem.  Then you would get an answer something like Keen-amateur's comment, or Henno Brandsma's answer #1. 
But you might want to mimic the style of the proof that you were shown as much as possible to ensure that you're showing all of the detail that they expect and using the notation that they want.

Comment: You can often take a theorem (and its proof) and turn this into a dual theorem (and proof), by interchanging intersection and union, open and closed, etc; this trick is very useful (and not only in topology).  You can often also prove the dual theorem as a corollary of the original theorem by applying complements and the de Morgan laws, but the details of this vary between contexts, so it's probably less useful to be able to do that.  Still, you might want to try writing down both ways for the extra practice.

Comment: @TobyBartels  It is not a homework problem. Also, tanks for advice regarding dual theorem. I will surely try doing this. Many times authors give such corollarirs is real analysis and topology.

Comment: Good, then you don't have to worry about his you're ‘supposed’ to do it.  But yes, keep looking for dual theorems; they are all over the place.  In analysis, topology, and algebra too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising comments, essentially:

1. You don't need to use $F_\sigma$ sets at all. It should be well-known that $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ is countable and so if $G_n = \bigcap_{m \in \Bbb N} O^{(n)}_m$ is a sequence of $G_\delta$'s in a space $X$ (so all $O^{(n)}_m$ are open sets) then 
   $$\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N} G_n = \bigcap_{(n,m) \in \Bbb N \times \Bbb N} O^{(n)}_m$$ is also a countable intersection of open sets, and hence a $G_\delta$.
2. But if $F_\sigma$ are absolutely necessary, apply de Morgan twice: $$\left(\bigcap_n \bigcap_m O^{(n)}_m\right)^\complement  =\bigcup_n \left(\bigcap_m O^{(n)}_m \right)^\complement = \bigcup_n \bigcup_m \left(O^{(n)}_m\right)^\complement $$
   so the complement of $\bigcap_n G_n$ is an $F_\sigma$ (a countable union of $F_\sigma$ sets was supposed to be known) and so the set itself is $G_\delta$. But IMHO this is too roundabout a way.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma  thank you very much